# Is there a way to dynamically change the base_url in a symfony project based on reverse proxy header

Tags: symfony, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm working on an app, with the front(vueJS) and back(symfony with API-platform) separated on the same domain.
We have an NGINX reverse proxy that redirects url base on these rule :

- domain.com/ -> front container on port 7000
- domain.com/api -> back container on port 8000
- domain.com/preview-mrXXX/ -> front container on port 7XXX
- domain.com/api/preview-mrXXX/ -> back container on port 8XXX

The problem is that the symfony assets aren't found because the request are on the root url and not the api or preview url.
e.g:
request goes to `https://example.com/bundles/apiplatform/web.png`
instead of `https://example.com/api/bundles/apiplatform/web.png`

I could pass a base_url in some header with nginx but I still need to configure symfony to requests on `/api/` rather than `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the base_url for assets in each container for the Framework configuration file. (from the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#base-urls).

Since you need it to be dynamic, you can create an .env.local file in each container with the `base_url` for that particular container. Then in the Framework configuration file mentioned above, you can set the value to `%base_url%`(the variable you created in the .env.local file) so that it will dynamically resolve to the correct value based on your env. You can refer to more information on env configuration here. https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html

UPDATE: You can also set the value to a real environment variable (from your shell or OS) by using `'%env(resolve:ENV_VAR)%'` (therefore avoiding defining it in the .env.local file). Relevant documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-based-on-environment-variables

Comment: could it be done from the environnements variables passed to the container in my docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: Yes, you can set it to env variables in the shell. Check the updated answer.